# Need help on how to loop through a script

Tags: powershell, loops, for-loop

I have some code which i want to run, it is a powershell script which creates network shares, assigns permissions and adds permissions to security groups and adds a user to that group. I have built the code and tested it and it works however now I need to loop it for a list of users in a CSV with a variable called samAccountName

Added a simple for which I have not tried just yet, I have no test environment

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\bhabib\makeshares.csv" | ForEach-Object {
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $_."samAccountName" -Path "OU=user,DC=domain,DC=com,DC=com"
New-ADGroup -Name "Write_share_$($_."samAccountName")" -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Domain -DisplayName "Write_Share_$($_."samAccountName")" -Path "OU=$($_."samAccountName"),OU=user,OU=blabla,DC=domain,Dc=domain,DC=com"
New-ADGroup -Name "Read_share_$($_."samAccountName")" -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Domain -DisplayName "Read_Share_$($_."samAccountName")" -Path "OU=$($_."samAccountName"),OU=user,OU=blabla,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=com"
New-Item -Path "D:\Shares\$($_."samAccountName")\MyDocuments" -ItemType "directory" -Force
$securitygroupwrite = "Write_share_$($_."samAccountName")"
$securitygroupread = "Read_share_$($_."samAccountName")"
New-SMBShare -Name $_."samAccountName" -Path "D:\Shares\$($_."samAccountName")\MyDocuments" -FullAccess "Administrators" -ChangeAccess $securitygroupwrite -ReadAccess $securitygroupread
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_."samAccountName" -MemberOf "Write_share_$($_."samAccountName")"
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_."samAccountName" -MemberOf "Read_share_$($_."samAccountName")"
$acl = Get-Acl "D:\Shares\$($_."samAccountName")\MyDocuments"
$AccessRuleWrite = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(“UPN\Write_share_$($_."samAccountName")","FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None","Allow")
$AccessRuleExecute = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(“UPN\Read_share_$($_."samAccountName")","ReadAndExecute","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None","Allow")
$AccessRuleRead = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(“UPN\Read_share_$($_."samAccountName")","Read","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRuleWrite)
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRuleRead)
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRuleExecute)
$acl | Set-Acl 
$acl = Get-Acl "D:\Shares\$($_."samAccountName")\MyDocuments"
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You should always have a test environment. **ACTIVE DIRECTORY is a pain to restore through snapshots.** I really recommend you build a test environment. It's not hard and you won't be sorry.

However it does looks like your for loop is setup correctly. You don't need to have quotes around the `samAccountName` variable. But it does hurt either.

Your script would probably be more stable if you explicitly list the domain controller with the `-Server` parameter.

You can use the `-whatif` parameter to aid in the testing process.

Comment: [WhatIf](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2146461-script-powershell-whatif-not-working) is not always implemented on the functions he is calling.